# For how long did the Pharaoh kill Israelite new born boys and leave the girls alive?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, pharaoh

From the bible we know that Pharaoh commanded the Israelite boys to be killed and the girls spared and this was done to kill the leader that would later grow up to overthrow the Pharaoh's rule.

Moses lived in the household of Pharaoh for sometime and then fled Egypt and returned after many years.

Did Pharaoh continue to kill Israelite boys this whole entire time until the Pharaoh met his end?

Answer (score 1):

[Sotah 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.12b.13?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi) says the decree was canceled as soon as Moses was placed in the water:

> Pharaoh’s astrologers saw that the savior of the Jewish people would
> be stricken by water. Therefore, they arose and decreed: “Every son
> that is born you shall cast into the river” (Exodus 1:22); they
> thought that their vision indicated that Moses would be killed in the
> water. Once Jochebed cast Moses into the water, although he was
> protected in an ark, the astrologers said: We no longer see in the
> stars anything like that sign we saw as to the downfall of the leader
> of the Jews by water, and therefore at that moment they canceled their
> decree. But they did not know that what they saw foretold that Moses
> would be stricken on account of the waters of Meribah.

Comment: I see. But until Moses came back with clear signs from God to Moses, the Pharaoh must have continued to oppress the Israelites by taking their daughters as slaves for entertainment and forcing their sons into slavery. Is this true?

Comment: I haven't heard about taking their daughters for entertainment, but yes, the slavery continued until they fled Egypt.

Comment: So it was slavery that continued until they left Egypt but not killing of the newborn boys?

Comment: Yes, that's right.